# Fetch API data to store on own server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, api, server

I’m using an API in my app and now I was suggested to use the API data to store it on my own server and spread the data to the user from there. The data needs to refresh every 10 seconds. Unfortunately I‘ve never done this kind of a backend setup. 
I thought to write a script which runs on my server that fetches the data from the API, then uploads the needed information on my server and repeats that every 10 seconds. But would that be the most efficient way to handle it, or is that a very bad way to do it?
Also is it recommended to use Node.js for that or is it just as fine to just use simple php scripts or JavaScript to fetch and store it?

**Edit**:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
const port = 3000;
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';

var number = 0;
var jsonResult;
const url = "xyz"

setInterval(() => {
     request(url, function (error, response, body) {
         
         fs.writeFile('test.json', body, (err) => {
            if (err){
               throw err;
            }
            console.log('Data written to file');
         });
         
         
         fs.readFile('test.json', (err, data)=>{
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            jsonResult = data;
            
         });
         
     });
    number++;
    console.log("call: " + number);
}, 5000)      
         
         
    
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.end(jsonResult);
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to poll for the data from an API on your server and store it to a database. If you're using nodejs on your server that's what you'll want to use. The guide here: https://medium.com/@xaviergeerinck/creating-a-non-blocking-polling-system-in-node-js-with-settimeout-and-eventemitter-4aaa098d25fb looks pretty good based on a quick reading

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter yeah exactly like polling. I‘m just not sure what‘s the best way to go there - I want to fetch JSON data, store them and show them just the same. Do you think node.js is the best for that task, or would it be just as fine to go without it?

Comment: I'd approach it using nodejs personally -- seems the most modern and well supported way of doing it (cron job would work too). If you're not doing any client/browser interaction then handling it with frontend JavaScript would be the wrong way to go and just needlessly add an extra layer.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter okay, I will try it like this then. Thank you very much so far, at further questions I might come back to you :) but could it be done with simple php scripting as well theoretically, it would leave it processed fully backend then as well, without a frontend layer, wouldn‘t it?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with server-side php as well, but node is a lot more powerful so it's really worth getting used to if you've got the choice. That's just my personal opinion though.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter would you mind taking a look at my edit? I played a little around and got to a solution that repeats fetching a json from an url, stores and shows it. Would that be a way it could work, or is it really bad thought through? I‘m aware that the part with writing and reading could be replaced by showing it directly but I thought like this data could be shown too if there‘s nothing to fetch from the api server due to an error